# c# Dispatching Extension Methods based on Value not Reference

Tags: c#, polymorphism, extension-methods, static-polymorphism

Given the following 2 extension methods

```
public static string getIDPropertyName(this object value)
{
    return "ID";
}

public static string getIDPropertyName<IDType>(this EntityRestIdentityDescriber<IDType> entityIdentityDescriber)
{
    return entityIdentityDescriber.propertyNameDescribingID();
}
```

and the following 2 invocations

```
//arrange

object test = new CustomEntityRestModelIdentity();
//test.UserName = "KKK";
//act
var actual = test.getIDPropertyName(); //calls the first extension method
var actual2 = (test as CustomEntityRestModelIdentity).getIDPropertyName(); //calls the second extension method
```

How can I execute the second extension method even though its reference type is object but its value type is a EntityRestIdentityDescriber? I'm looking for static polymorphism.

Comment: Do you mean how can you call it without casting?

Comment: Extension methods are chosen at compile-time. You already have a workaround in the question (actual2).

Comment: @AliSheikhNezami this is no test lol. What I'm trying to do is via reflection landing up with an object and then calling getIDPropertyName in order to get the right method to execute in case the object implements EntityRestIdentityDescriber. If the object doesn't implement it, it defaults to the other method that returns ID. Is there no way to call the other method without casting or inheritance?

Comment: @buffjape I don't because I land up with an object due to reflection and want to execute the other method in case the object implements EntityRestIdentityDescriber on runtime

Answer (score 1):

*try this*

```
public static string getIDPropertyName(this object entityIdentityDescriber)
{
    if(entityIdentityDescriber is EntityRestIdentityDescriber<IDType>)
        return entityIdentityDescriber.propertyNameDescribingID();
    else
        return "id";
}
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of doing this earlier, but IDType is undefined and so I can't really cast because I don't know the value at runtime. I can't also remove hte Generic restriction because it is required elsewhere. Is there no other way other than Inheritance and dynamic polymorphism?

Answer (score 0):

You need `double dispatch`.`Double dispatch` determine dispatch based on the actual type at runtime

```cs
public class IdPropertyNameResolver
{
    public string GetIDPropertyName(object value)=>"ID";

    public string GetIDPropertyName<T>(EntityRestIdentityDescriber<T> value)=>
        value.propertyNameDescribingID();
}
//......do something
object o = new CustomEntityRestModelIdentity();
new IdPropertyNameResolver().GetIDPropertyName((dynamic)o);//CustomEntityRestModelIdentity id name
//......
```